# Zsh: make the up arrow skip identical commands

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history

In most Unix shells, the arrow-up `↑` key replaces the command that is being edited by the previous command in the history.
The history can be seen using the command `history`.

`↑` can be pressed more than one time to climb up in the history.

My question is:

## How can I configure my shell so that `↑` skips all commands identical to the current one?

Indeed I often enter many `make` in a row. When I want to enter again (or modify slightly) an older command I have to hit `↑` many times just to skip all the `make` commands.

*I know that `↑` is far from being the only tip that increase shell productivity.*

bonus:

- give a configuration working for the Bash shell.
- preserve the history (knowing that you typed a command many times in a row can be useful)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For zsh put this in your configuration:

```
setopt histignoredups
```

What it does, it will [ignore duplicated history entries](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-history_002c-ignoring-duplicates) during search.

The equivalent setting for bash is

```
HISTCONTROL=$HISTCONTROL:ignoredups
```

Comment: thanks, `setopt histignoredups` does the job but also suppress duplicate from the history

Comment: Yes, exactly. In most cases this is what you want. When you have seen a suggestion and you don't want it, you don't want to have this suggested again. It does not delete duplicates from history, btw.

Comment: You are right but I meant: future duplicates will not be added to the history.

Comment: They are added otherwise the other option called `histexpiredupsfirst` that I also use would not make sense. It makes duplicates expire first before looking at the age. (I am talking about zsh here)